# Flutter and Firebase Filter data

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'am kinda new in Flutter
I would like to know how can I get a snapshot of all messages in all groups where the user is a member of these group

in each users document there is groups array show list of joined group, it contains groupId_groupName

and in groups collections document there is members where it contains userId_userName

each group have messages collections

What is I need is to get the snapshot of all messages collections of a specific user.
I don't know if this is possible

Edited
the code that I made is:

```
getAllMessages() async {
    var query = db.collection("groups").where("members",
        arrayContains: 'fKceqEUAhSWGDuV2PxSX6dhxnfI2_Khaldun');
    var rs1 = await query.get();
    var myList = [];
    rs1.docs.forEach((element) {
      myList.add(element.data());
    });
    List myMessages = [];
    for (var element in myList) {
      await db
          .collection('groups')
          .doc(element['groupId'])
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy("time", descending: true)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        myMessages.add(value.docs);
      });
    }
    var flat = myMessages.expand((i) => i).toList();
    var realMessages = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) {
      realMessages.add(flat[i].data());
    }
    realMessages.sort(((a, b) => b['time'] - a['time']));
     return realMessages[0];
  }
```

this code return a json and I would like to get a snapshot or transform this to Stream I don't know if this is a good practice I would like to know how I could do it other way

This is User Collection

[image: This is user Collection]

---

This is Group Collection

[image: This is Group Collection]

Comment: You have to first take snapshot of user collection and then you get list of group

Comment: when tap on item of group you have to get message from group collection

Comment: I think it was possible to create, the first thing you need to do is create a `listview.builder` for the group array, and then when you click the child of the group design. you will be directed to a new screen and when you're in already navigate to a new screen. you can access the group collection using the index of uid you got from showing the child of the group. after that just retrieve all members and made a check for your self are you in the group or not

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e